# AS400.validateSignon() does not reset the failed signon attempts to 0. Need to know the PTF

Tags: ibm-midrange

AS400.validateSignon() does not reset the failed signon attempts to 0.
I am having issues when a user logs in with an incorrect password, the number of invalid password entry does not get reste to zeros after logging in with the correct password. 
There was an answer posted on site Dec 2012, but there was no mnetion what the PTF that was removed to resolve this issu.
What was the PTF removed?
Was this in V6r1 version?

Comment: Maybe you should add a little more information on what you are trying to do, and in which context I _guess_ you are using java?

Comment: Sorry, I added the extra details. This is on a AS400 Midrange Platform

Comment: Can't you use the QSYGETPH API to reset the count to 0 as I mentioned in an answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766412/as400-validatesignon-does-not-reset-the-failed-signon-attempts-to-0

Answer (score 0):

Failed attempts to what? If the user is connecting the IFS, the invalid password count wouldn't get reset until either you perform a CHGUSRPRF or restart NETSERVER. What version of iSeries are you running?